# Alternative to ask-concurrent

Tags: netlogo

I started today learning Netlogo based on an existing simulation which uses `ask-concurrent`. When I looked up the documentation to find what `ask-concurrent` does, I found the following: `NOTE: The following information is included only for backwards compatibility. We don't recommend using the ask-concurrent primitive at all in new models.`

However, it doesn't say anything about alternatives to this function. What should I use instead of `ask-concurrent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular `ask`. If you find that changes the meaning of the code in a way that you consider undesirable, then in order to advise you on what to do about it, we will need to know the details of your code.

http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#ask-concurrent contains several examples of pieces of code that use `ask-concurrent` and how they can be written using regular `ask` instead.